# Using ra-data-graphql with AppSync GraphQL API

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, react-admin

I'm trying to use react-admin with AWS Amplify library and AWS AppSync SDK.

I can't wrap my head around how to use use ra-data-graphql/ra-data-graphql-simple with AWS AppSync API for querying/mutating data. Trying to do a very basic test with `master/examples/demo` from https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Currently I'm trying to use dataProvider similar to below:

```
src/dataProvider/appsync.js:

import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import AWSAppSyncClient, { AUTH_TYPE } from 'aws-appsync';
import buildGraphQLProvider, { buildQuery } from 'ra-data-graphql-simple';
import { __schema as schema } from './schema';

const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
  url: "https://xxxx.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql",
  region: "us-east-1,
  auth: {
    type: AUTH_TYPE.AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS,
    jwtToken: async () => (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
  }

const myBuildQuery = introspection => (fetchType, resource, params) => {
    const builtQuery = buildQuery(introspection)(fetchType, resource, params);

    if (resource === 'listings' && fetchType === 'GET_LIST') {
        return {
            ...builtQuery,
            query: gql`
                query getListings {
                    data: getListings {
                        items {
                            listingId
                        }
                    }
                }`,
        };
    }

    return builtQuery;
}

export default buildGraphQLProvider({ client: client, introspection: { schema }, buildQuery: myBuildQuery })
```

```
src/dataProvider/index.js:

export default type => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'graphql':
            return import('./graphql').then(factory => factory.default());
        case 'appsync':
            return import('./appsync');
        default:
            return import('./rest').then(provider => provider.default);
    }
};
```

```
src/App.js:

...
import dataProviderFactory from './dataProvider';
...

class App extends Component {
    state = { dataProvider: null };
    async componentDidMount() {
        const dataProvider = await dataProviderFactory(
            process.env.REACT_APP_DATA_PROVIDER
        );
        this.setState({ dataProvider });
    }
...
```

```
src/dashboard/Dashboard.js:

...
    fetchData() {
        this.fetchListings();
    }

    async fetchListings() {
        const { dataProvider } = this.props;
        const { data: reviews } = await dataProvider(GET_LIST, 'listings');
        console.log(listings)
    }
...
```

Currently no data is returned from the API and the exception is thrown on `await dataProvider(GET_LIST, 'listings');` saying `call: [object Model] is not a function`, however I see that buildGraphQLProvider promise was resolved succesfully to a function.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong and what is the right way to approach the task?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I could be wrong, but your query looks a bit odd for amplify/AppSync - based on generated code from `amplify add api`, wouldn't 
`query listListings { 
  items { 
    id
    ...
  } 
}` be the correct query?